# Objects are not valid as a React child when trying to render object data inside modal

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to print an object but I get the above error.
This is my code:

```
        <Modal
          mask={false}
          title={that.state.selectedDbName}
          visible={statsmodalVisible}
          onCancel={that.handleOtherCancel}
          style={{ minWidth: '75%', textAlign: 'center',}}
          footer = {
            [<Button type="primary" key="modalDismissButton"
            onClick={this.handleOtherCancel}> Dismiss</Button>]
          }
        >
          {data}
        </Modal>
```

Here **data** is the object that I am trying to show in a modal.
I also tried this, **data.toString()** But the output was `[object Object]`

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: @bennygenel thanks this works.. But not 100% properly. Any alternatives?

Comment: If you don't give 100% properly information about what you are trying to do and whats the problem exactly you can't get a 100% properly working answer. please check [ask] for more info

Comment: @bennygenel the problem is related to the ant design modal as the content is going out of that modal. So, not related to this question. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the contents of an object, you can use

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

This will serialize the object to appear like this:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": ["value2", "value3"],
  "key3": {...},
  ...
}
```

It will ignore functions in the object.

Calling `data.toString()` will invoke the inner [toString function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) on the object. 
The default behavior in objects is indeed to print `[object Object]`.